# Interpolating Perl variables

Tags: perl

I want to interpolate a scalar variable inside another Perl variable. For example:

```
my $var = "test";
my $test_1 = "DONE\n";
```

I want to print value of `$test_1`, but by making use of `$var`.
I want to interpolate `$var` first and resulting its value as `$test_1`. Can we achieve this?

Comment: It would be better to explain what you're doing, as what you want  is bad practice.

Comment: I want interpolate value of 1st variable & create variable of value I am getting from 1st variable. (Little confusing I know)

I tried with $$var but not getting result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `my $test_1` declares a lexical variable, we can't use a symbolic reference like `${"test_1"}` or `"${$var . "_1"}`. Perl's symbolic references ignore lexical variables from `my` and look for global variables.

We might pass a string of Perl code to `eval()`, which can see its caller's lexical variables:

```
my $var = "test";
my $test_1 = "DONE\n";
print eval("\${${var}_1}");
```

But calling `eval()` is dangerous if someone can inject Perl code:

```
my $var = 'a} if 0; system "echo EVIL"; ${test';
my $test_1 = "DONE\n";
print eval("\${${var}_1}");
```

Instead, we can make a hash where the keys are names, and the values are references to our local variables:

```
my $var = "test";
my $test_1 = "DONE\n";
my %hash = (
    test_1 => \$test_1,
);
print ${$hash{$var . "_1"}};
```

It's probably simpler to lose the `$test_1` variable and just store its value in `$hash{test_1}`:

```
my $var = "test";
my %hash = (
    test_1 => "DONE\n",
);
print ${$hash{$var . "_1"}};
```

Comment: OK; fair enough.  I've removed my comment; you may remove your response; I'll remove this shortly.

Answer (score 8):

```
...
$hello = "ciao";
$$hello = "salut"; # $ciao = "salut";
print $ciao; # prints "salut"
...
```

This practice is **not recommended**.

#### EDIT1: (ULTRA-discouraged)

To fit your data, you could do this:

```
$var = "test";
${$var."_1"} = "done\n";
print $test_1; # prints `done\n`
```

#### END EDIT1

It'll be better to **use hashes**.

```
...
my %hash = ();
my $key = "ciao"; # in the example seen before this was `$hello`
$hash{$key} = "salut"; # $hash{ciao} = "salut";
print $hash{ciao}; # will print "salut".
...
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to use a variable as another variable's name. This is a terrible idea. There is always a better approach. If you explained why you want to do this then we could help you find what the better alternative is (it probably involves using a hash).

Mark Dominus wrote a [series](http://perl.plover.com/varvarname.html) of [three](http://perl.plover.com/varvarname2.html) [articles](http://perl.plover.com/varvarname3.html) explaining exactly why this is a terrible idea.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is called a symbolic reference, whereby a scalar variable is used as the name of another variable. You can probably feel the sweet smell of danger. But anyway:

```
$var = "test";
$test_1 = "DONE\n";
print ${"${var}_1"};
```

As pointed out by Amon, symbolic references don't work with lexical `my` variables.

Comment: symrefs only work with package variables, not with `my` variables. Change the `my $test_1` to `our $test_1`, and it'll work.